# snake and ladder game player position keeps starting at zero swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a snake and ladder game for an array of players.

```
//board set up

let finalSquare = 25
var playersLocation: Int = 0

var players: [String: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 0, "c":0]



var won = false

var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08

board

//roll the dice
func rollDice ()->Int {
    let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
    return value
}


var count: Int = 0


while(won == false){

for (player, location ) in players{
    //this is the player first location
    print("player \(player) is now at \(location)")

    // roll the dice and move the player

    var advance =  location + rollDice()
    print("now I roll the dice and player \(player) move \(advance) step ")

    //check if the index is still on the board, and if it hits the magic number
    if advance < board.count {
        //create the magic number and plus with the advance
        var magicNumber: Int = board[advance]
        print("the magic number is \(magicNumber)")

        //adding the magicNumber to advance
        advance = advance + magicNumber

        //check the number after magicNumber added
        print("after adding the magic number, the current position is \(advance)")
    }
    //check if the player exceeds the board number
    if advance >= board.count {
        var won = true
        print("player \(player) won")
        break
    }else{
        advance = advance + rollDice()
        print("not win yet, after I add the number from the roll dice it advance to \(advance)")
        won = false
    }
    }
}
```

here is a snippet from debugging text:

```
//player b is now at 0//
//now I roll the dice and player b move 5 step //
//the magic number is 0//
//after adding the magic number, the current position is 5//
//not win yet, after I add the number from the roll dice it advance to 6//
```

then after it complete for all the players, it return to the player b:

```
//player b is now at 0//
//now I roll the dice and player b move 6 step// 
//the magic number is 11//
//after adding the magic number, the current position is 17//
//not win yet, after I add the number from the roll dice it advance to 22//
```

it seems that each time a new round start, it does not pick up from its previous position and always start from zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot update new location for players after they roll dice.

```
//check the number after magicNumber added
print("after adding the magic number, the current position is \(advance)")

// update the player location                    
players[player] = advance
```

Comment: thanks ,, it did store the advance location of the player ! but why doesn't it break once any of the player won?

Comment: Fix this line: `var won = true`. Just `won = true`, do not re-declare `var won`